# logger messages in zipkin

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I am new to sleuth and zipkin. I have logged some messages and sleuth is appending trace id and space id for those messages. I am using zipkin to visualize it. I am able to see timings at different microservices. Can we see logger messages(we put at different microservices) in zipkin UI by trace id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. You can use tools like Elasticsearch Logstash Kibana to visualize it. You can go to my repo https://github.com/marcingrzejszczak/docker-elk and run `./   getReadyForConference.sh`, it will start docker containers with the ELK stack, run the apps, curl the request to the apps so that you can then check them in ELK.